# Feature Name Mismatch when Predicting on Test and Train using XGboost

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I am trying to use XGBoostRegressor to predict a test and train set; however, every time I run the code to generate a prediction I get a feature mismatch error.

The code below shows the model I created, and how I select 1 column of the XTrain training data each time to fit a model. In addition, I split the train and test data using SKLearn's Test Train split which means rows were taken randomly to create the train and test data (80/20 Split).

When I run the prediction "y_predfin" and "y_pred", this is when I get a feature mismatch error.

I've tried the following:
**Converting all data to numpy array's**, **Reshaped my 1 column data for the loop since XGBoost doesn't take 1 column, Replace Eval_Set with a manual calculation for Train and Test error.**

```
modelTrain = XGBRegressor(colsample_bytree=0.4,
                 gamma=0,                 
                 learning_rate=0.07,
                 max_depth=3,
                 min_child_weight=1.5,
                 n_estimators=10000,                                                                    
                 reg_alpha=0.75,
                 reg_lambda=0.45,
                 subsample=0.6,
                 seed=650318,
                 early_stopping_rounds = 10)

Columns = X_train.columns
print(Columns)
X_train = X_train.values
Y_train = Y_train.values
X_test = X_test.values
Y_test = Y_test.values
XTrainShuffeled = XTrainShuffeled.values
Y_testuse = np.reshape(Y_test, (1,-1))
Y_trainuse = np.reshape(Y_train, (1,-1))

for i in range(len(XFinalData) - 1):
    X_trainuse = np.reshape(X_train[:,i+1], (1,-1))
    X_testuse = np.reshape(X_test[:,i+1], (1,-1))
    modelTrain.fit(X_trainuse, Y_trainuse, eval_metric = "error", verbose = True)
    y_predfin = modelTrain.predict(X_testuse)
    y_pred = modelTrain.predict(X_trainuse)
    TrainErrorMSE = mean_squared_error(Y_trainuse, y_pred)
    TestErrorMSE = mean_squared_error(Y_testuse, y_predfin)
    Importance.update({str(Columns[i+1]) + " Importance" : modelTrain.feature_importances_})
    TrainError.update({str(Columns[i+1]) + " TrainError" : TrainErrorMSE})
    TestError.update({str(Columns[i+1]) + " TestError" : TestErrorMSE})
```

I hoped to get predictions, but instead I get a feature mismatch error when predicting using the X_testuse as the amount of rows do not match the amount of rows on the X_trainuse (80/20 split).

Thank you for the help!